# Netbeans error in installing glassfish server 3.0? "I/O Exception: Invalid argument: connect"

Tags: netbeans, glassfish-3

I'm trying to install glassfish server using netbeans but it isn't working. I'm trying to download it with netbeans but it keeps saying "I/O Exception: Invalid argument: connect". anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: I suggest going to http://glassfish.java.net/ and getting the version your want.